# How to use Parse push notifications using dotnet REST API in Android?

Tags: c#, android, rest, parse-platform

I am new to Android,I am going to develop push notifications using parse.com in my android application,and my REST Api are from Dotnet.I have gone through this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/06/android-push-notifications-using-parse-com/) and i am not able to find out from where should i give reference to REST Api.please assist me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](http://hintdesk.com/google-cloud-messaging-asp-net-web-api-and-android-client/) how we can Combine Google Cloud Message, ASP.NET Web API and Android Client together. I think the concept is still same when you use other Push Service.